# .NET Core on Mac for developing REST web service

Tags: asp.net, .net, macos, rest

I have a simple question:
Is it possible to develop a REST web service on a Mac laptop, using the latest Core.NET and the new Mac Visual Studio tooling? The service is to be deployed in Window server/iis eventually, but I need productive environment.

Also, as I will be interfacing with SharePoint 2013 server, will I be able to use the above environment for OAuth, claims, etc during Mac development cycles (e.g are the libraries/assemblies/whatever included in .NET Core for Mac)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that Core and Visual Studio for mac is on a very early stage. Be prepared for problems if you take this road... a safer approach for now would probably be to use Core until you detect any serious incompatibility and move to standard Windows .NET framework if you do.

You can target Core and .NET Framework at the same time if you have to move to Windows and add preprocessor directives to skip incompatible code for Core platform...later you can revisit full migration to Core when reaches a more mature state.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a small project using ASP.NET Core to provide data to my Xamarin Forms project.

Developing on Mac with latest Visual Studio. I have a mobile app which consumes data from an ASP.NET Core project which follows the REST architecture.

Everything is running smooth and fine. I was really impressed at the beginning how far easy it is to make it work on a Mac.

Except for the ASP.NET project, I'm using .NET Standard library everywhere (even for Xamarin Forms). It's very good. Having httpClient, httpStatusCode etc, socket etc out of the box without having to use dependency injections feels sooooo goooooood :D

No need to use IoC and abstraction for basic things. It makes REST architecture easier to use and your solution lighter IMHO.

I love .NET Core and .NET Standard. Once you try it, you won't go back.
Give it a try !